# How to add a file to a dvc-tracked folder without pulling the whole folder's content?

Tags: dvc

Let's say I am working inside a git/dvc repo. There is a folder `data` containing 100k small files. I track it with DVC as a single element, as recommended by the doc:

```sh
dvc add data
```

and because in my experience, DVC is kinda slow when tracking that many files one by one.

I clone the repo on another workspace, and now I have the `data.dvc` file locally but none of the actual files inside yet. I want to add a file named `newfile.txt` to the `data` folder and track it with DVC. Is there a way to do this *without pulling the whole content of `data` locally* ?

What I have tried for now:

1. Adding the `data` folder again:

   ```
   mkdir data
   mv path/to/newfile.txt data/newfile.txt
   dvc add data
   ```

   The `data.dvc` file is built again from the local state of `data` which only contains `newfile.txt` so this doesn't work.
2. Adding the file as a single element in `data` folder:

   ```
    dvc add data/newfile.txt
   ```

   I get :

   ```
    Cannot add 'data/newfile.txt', because it is overlapping with other DVC tracked output: 'data'. 
    To include 'data/newfile.txt' in 'data', run 'dvc commit data.dvc'
   ```
3. Using dvc commit as suggested

   ```
    mkdir data
    mv path/to/newfile.txt data/newfile.txt
    dvc commit data.dvc
   ```

   Similarly as 1., the `data.dvc` is rebuilt again from local state of `data`.

Comment: re `DVC is kinda slow when tracking that many files one by one.`

The limitation is more in the file system. The way DVC works is that it creates a .dvc metafile for each file/dir you want to track as an entity. Adding 100k files separately then requires managing 100k metafiles which involves lots of I/O operations. That's why DVC allows granularity in most of its commands even if you track entire directories, e.g. you can `dvc add data; dvc push data/some/file`

Answer (score 2):

> I clone the repo on another workspace, and now I have the data.dvc file locally but none of the actual files inside yet (haven't `dvc pull`ed). I want to add a file to the data folder and track it with DVC. Is there a way to do this without pulling the whole content of data locally ?

Interesting question. I think there is no easy way to do this now because in this other machine if you `dvc add data` again but with only one file in there, DVC will think you deleted all the other files, create a new cached version of the data dir (containing only the new file), and update the .dvc file accordingly (as you discovered).

You could open a feature request in https://github.com/iterative/dvc.org/issues.